# How to calculate $\oint F\cdot dr$ on the curve from the intersection of plane $z=2x$ and paraboloid using Stokes' theorem?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

> Calculate $\oint F\cdot dr$ on the curve which is created by the intersection of plane $z=2x$ and paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$. Suppose the direction of the curve is anti-clockwise. Let the field be $F=\langle 0,0,y\rangle$.

First the definition of $\oint F\cdot dr$ used in my class:
$$
\oint F\cdot dr=\oint F\cdot\langle dx,dy,dz\rangle
$$
Now according to Stokes' theorem:
$$
\oint F\cdot dr=\iint \operatorname{curl}F\cdot n\cdot dS
$$
where $n$ is the normal unit vector to the surface.

As far as I understand our curve is a circle with the center at $(1,0)$ and with radius $r=1$:
$$
x^2+y^2=2x\\
(x-1)^2+y^2=1
$$
so $n=\frac{\langle -2,0,1\rangle}{\sqrt 5}$
Therefore:
$$
\iint_D \operatorname{curl}F\cdot n\cdot dS=\iint_D \langle 1,0,0\rangle\cdot\frac{\langle -2,0,1\rangle}{\sqrt 5}dS=\\
=-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\iint_D dS
$$
Because our curve is the circumference of the circle so $\iint_DdS=\pi r^2=\pi$.

Thus $\oint F\cdot dr=-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 5}$.

But the answer is incorrect as the correct solution is $-2\pi$. I assume that if I didn't normalize $n$ my answer would be correct but $n$ should be normalized as far as I understand.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the boundary of the surface in the plane projects a circle of radius $1$ onto the $xy$ plane. The surface on the plane itself is not a circle nor not even a disk, to my imagination it would be an ellipse. As such it's area is not $\pi$ but rather $\sqrt{5}\pi$. This factor shows up because of tilting.

We are looking at the surface $S$ with $(x-1)^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $z=2x$. We wish to calculate,

$$\iint_{S} dS$$

Because $z=2x$ we have $z_x=2$ and $z_y=0$, hence $\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}=\sqrt{5}$ and $dS=\sqrt{5} dA$, so:

$$\iint_{S} dS=\sqrt{5} \iint_{(x-1)^2+y^2\ \leq 1}  dA$$

$$=\sqrt{5} \pi$$

Comment: Your answer is still not the correct one.

Comment: How? $\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}} \sqrt{5} \pi=-2\pi$.

Comment: I thought you meant $\sqrt 5\pi$ is the final answer, my bad

Comment: Yes you're right, I needed to take into account that $0\le r\le 2\cos \theta$. If I had an integral like $\int_D 1\cdot dS$ and $D=x^2+y^2=a^2$ then $\int_D dS=\pi a^2$ right?

Comment: If the surface was flat (parallel) to the $xy$ plane that would be correct, but once we have tilting we need to account for this @Yos

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector for the curve is determined by the plane $z = 2x$. Hence, we have $\textbf{n} = (-2,0, 1)$. You shouldn't be multiplying by $1/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: First as far as I see the normal vector should be $\langle -2,0,1\rangle$, there's no $x$ in there. Secondly, doesn't $n$ have to be a normal **unit** vector? Otherwise wouldn't we get different results for $\oint F\cdot dr$ for each different normal (proportional vector)?

Comment: Using the definition of the surface integral, the normal vector must be unit length (because the definition is the scalar surface integral of the normal component of the vector field. To find this you can just dot the vector field with a unit normal). When computing this via a parametrization, you use the normal that you find my crossing the derivatives of your parametrization together, this normal will not be unit in general, but if you go through the computations it turns out to be ok.

Comment: So by your logic I could've used this normal $n=\langle -4,0,2\rangle$ as well as it's proportional to the original normal vector. But the result would've been different.

Comment: @Yos, $$ \iint \textbf{curl}(F) \cdot d\textbf{S} = \iint \textbf{curl}(F) \cdot \frac{\textbf{n}}{\|\textbf{n}\|} \|\textbf{n}\| \ dA = \iint \textbf{curl}(F) \cdot \textbf{n} \ dA$$

Comment: @Yos: No, You missed completely what James was saying. The normal vector $(-2,0,1)$ will be the one that arises from parametrizing the curve with say $\gamma$ and computing $\gamma' \times \gamma''$. But there is no need to do this since the curve is a plane curve and we know the plane. All I was saying is that you don't have to adjust the scaling when you have a parametrization because you end up multiplying the result by the length again.